# Executing Yeoman/nodejs actions in specific order

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman

Starting out making a Yeoman generator for the first time... What I want to do is fetch a VM from a repo, and optionally an existing codebase from another repo to the same directory.

When I clone the repo, I want to remove the .git info (libgit2 does not support depth or other options, so I use rimraf to strip out the git history), copy and rename two config files, and replace strings in those files with input supplied from the user during the 'prompting' phase of Yeoman.

I am having trouble with blocking progress until actions are complete. Here is what I have so far. It mostly appears to work... except replace() is not quite working as I would expect:

```
configuring: function() {
    var done = this.async();
    var vm_repository = "https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm.git";
    var vm_directory = this.destinationRoot() + '/drupalvm';

    this.log(chalk.yellow('Cloning DrupalVM from ' + vm_repository));

    clone(vm_repository, vm_directory, done)
      .then(function() {
        rimraf(vm_directory + '/.*', function(error) {
          if (error) return console.log(error);
        });
        rimraf(vm_directory + '/docs', function(error) {
          if (error) return console.log(error);
        });
        rimraf(vm_directory + '/examples', function(error) {
          if (error) return console.log(error);
        });
        rimraf(vm_directory + '/mkdocs.yml', function(error) {
          if (error) return console.log(error);
        });
        console.log('Repository cloned successfully.');
        done();
      })
      .catch(function(error) { console.log(error) });
    },

  writing: function() {
    var done = this.async();
    var vm_directory = this.destinationRoot() + '/drupalvm';

    fs.copy(this.destinationRoot() + '/drupalvm/example.config.yml', this.destinationRoot() + '/drupalvm/config.yml', function (error) {
      if (error) return console.log(error);
    });

    fs.copy(this.destinationRoot() + '/drupalvm/example.drupal.make.yml', this.destinationRoot() + '/drupalvm/drupal.make.yml', function (error) {
      if (error) return console.log(error);
    });

    done();
  },

  end: function() {
    this.log('what 4');
    // rewrite values with user input
    replace({
      regex: "/vagrant_machine_name\: drupalvm/",
      replacement: "vagrant_machine_name: " + this.vagrant_machine_name,
      paths: [this.destinationRoot() + '/drupalvm/config.yml'],
      recursive: false,
      silent: false,
    });

    replace({
      regex: "vagrant_ip: 192.168.88.88",
      replacement: "vagrant_ip: " + this.vagrant_ip,
      paths: [this.destinationRoot() + '/drupalvm/config.yml'],
      recursive: false,
      silent: false,
    });
  },
```

Is this exceptionally efficient.. maybe not. Pretty new to yeoman/nodejs scripting.

Where am I going wrong? Also, how can I pass context and variables down through functions as arguments? They keep coming up as undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues here and it'll be hard to point everything that is wrong. Basically, you need to understand how asynchronous actions works in Node - this is not Yeoman specific.

So for the sake of simplicity, I'd say start by using `rimraf.sync()`. So that will run synchronously.

Also, take a look at Yeoman file helpers to copy/replace/templates/etc etc http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html - These helpers are also synchronous so you won't have to handle the flow manually.